# WSO2 Idenity Server XACML and XML Encoding for UTF-8 and Special Characters

Tags: utf-8, authorization, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

Testing a String compare operation under the XACML "Try-It" tool of the WSO2 based PDP, I detect some issues with ascii and non-ascii character definitions in XACML (XML) source code and its variables. Below some examples:

```
São Paulo = São Paulo =>  match is True 

S&#227;o Paulo =  São Paulo => match is True 

&#83;&#227;&#111;&#32;&#80;&#97;&#117;&#108;&#111; = "São Paulo" => match is True

S&atilde;o Paulo = "São Paulo" => match is False

S&#x00E3o Paulo = "São Paulo" => match is False
```

All source use a preceding header of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The translation of variables does not 100% match the expected behaviour which is "True". Is there a hint how to improve the hit rate for "True" when using the WSO2 policy editors?